# xslt empty tag check

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Legs>
  <Leg>
    <LegNo>1</LegNo>
    <RaceInfo>
      <RaceNo>1</RaceNo>
      <Name/>
      <BaseDistance>2140</BaseDistance>
      <StartMethod Code="A"/>
      <StartTime>
        <Hour>13</Hour>
        <Minute>48</Minute>
      </StartTime>
      <Status>OpenForSell</Status>
      <NumberOfStarts>10</NumberOfStarts>
    </RaceInfo>
    <Starts>
      <Start>
        <StartNo>1</StartNo>
        <Horse>
          <RegNo>578001020080423</RegNo>
          <Name>Mino</Name>
        </Horse>
        <Driver>
          <LicenseNo>29749</LicenseNo>
          <FirstName>Hovel</FirstName>
          <LastName>Helmen</LastName>
        </Driver>
        <Distance>2140</Distance>
        <Scratched>false</Scratched>
        <Ranking>2</Ranking>
      </Start>
      <Start>
        <StartNo>2</StartNo>
        <Horse>
          <RegNo>578001020080121</RegNo>
          <Name>Furderud Svarten</Name>
        </Horse>
        <Driver>
          <LicenseNo>4290</LicenseNo>
          <FirstName>Bjørn</FirstName>
          <LastName>Humborstad</LastName>
        </Driver>
        <Distance>2140</Distance>
        <Scratched>false</Scratched>
        <Ranking/>
      </Start>
    </Starts>
  </Leg>
</Legs>
```

And I am converting to XML with part of this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<p class="txt">
            <xsl:text>Rangering: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="found">
                <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="Legs[@ResultsComplete='true']/Leg">

                <xsl:value-of select="LegNo" />
                <xsl:text>. avd: </xsl:text>

                <xsl:call-template name="getRanking">
                    <xsl:with-param name="structure" select="Starts" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="winner" select="Winners/Winner/@StartNo" />

                </xsl:call-template>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Starts/Start/Scratched = 'true'">
                        <xsl:text> (str. </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Starts/Start[Ranking=0]/StartNo">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                                    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    <xsl:template name="getRanking">
        <xsl:param name="structure"/>
        <xsl:param name="counter"/>
        <xsl:param name="winner"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$structure/Start[Ranking=$counter]/StartNo = $winner">
                <xsl:value-of select="$structure/Start[Ranking=$counter]/StartNo"/>
                <!--<xsl:text> </xsl:text>-->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$structure/Start[Ranking=$counter]/StartNo"/>
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="getRanking">
                    <xsl:with-param name="structure" select="$structure"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter + 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="winner" select="$winner"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output shall be a list of numbers separated by comma. 
How ever. When I am hitting an empty tag, I am getting a `'FORG0001: Cannot convert string to double'` error.

I am using Saxon 9.4.0.6.

I have tried to add an if statement before the choose-block, but that does not seem to matter.

What I want to achieve is to skip the blocks that has empty Ranking elements.

Here is the desired output (which works when I don't have an empty ranking element:

```
<p class="txt">Rangering: 1. avd: 7 (str. 2, 6), 2. avd: 5, 3. avd: 1-6, 4. avd: 1-11 (str. 3, 6, 8, 12), 5. avd: 2-12-6 (str. 4, 5, 10).</p>
```

Comment: Your error is in the `[Ranking=$counter]` predicate. In any case, please include the template that calls `getRanking`, and include the expected output for your sample.

Comment: Added requested information. yes, the problem is in the Ranking=$counter predicate.

Comment: The XSLT you provide is syntactically invalid. And I don't see how it could produce the output you suggest. Your question is not complete.

Comment: Of course you could use `[number(Ranking) = $counter]`, but I suspect from the code I've seen so far that there is a way to simplify your entire approach.

Comment: Added more XML and more XSLT so it should be possible to do something with it. yes it could be that it is possible. At the same time there are some 'rules' I have to follow in order to get the expected result.

Comment: The XSLT is still syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initially call the **getRanking** template, instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:with-param name="structure" select="Starts" />
```

Try doing this, to filter out the **Start** elements with no ranking

```
<xsl:with-param name="structure" select="Starts/Start[Ranking != '']" />
```

Because the **structure** element no longer contains the **Starts** element, you also have to simplify the expressions in the **getRanking** element as follows:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$structure[Ranking=$counter]/StartNo = $winner">
          <xsl:value-of select="$structure[Ranking=$counter]/StartNo"/>
```

Having said all that, I am wondering if you could simplify the whole logic to just use an **xsl:for-each** loop here, instead of recursively calling the template...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Starts/Start[Ranking != '']">
   <xsl:sort select="Ranking" />
   <!-- existing code from getRanking template -->
```

And if you wanted to 'abort' the loop as soon as you found the winner, you could structure it as follows

```
<xsl:variable name="winnerRanking" select="Starts/Start[StartNo = $winner]/Ranking" />
<xsl:for-each select="Starts/Start[Ranking != ''][Ranking &lt;= $winnerRanking]">
   <xsl:sort select="Ranking" />
```

Comment: Hi Tim C, Thanks for helping out. Yes adding the /Start[Ranking !=''] helped a lot and worked like a charm. I have not tested your simpler version (I might in the future). 

I cannot use sorting as the order in the XML decides the order in the list I am to create. 

I have how ever noticed that even though the start with ranking equals to '' shall be in the list and so I have talked to the provider to see if they can do some changes to their XML-file.

Again: Thanks for all the help you provided!